# How to set active_link_to on child elements to set active only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to rails and I want to set `active_link_to` on child elements only. I'm using this gem https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to

Situation:

```
parent element path:
localhost:3000/columns  // This one is set to active when going to that specific page

child element path:
localhost:3000/columns/post // This one will also be active also but the parent element is also active
```

I have this navbar:

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <%= active_link_to columns_root_path, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
            Columns
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <%= active_link_to columns_post_path, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
            Post
        <% end %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I remove the `active_link_to` in the parent element If I only go to the child element. Because in my situation when I go to this path: `localhost:3000/columns/post` the `columns` and `post` path will be both set to active.

I have here in my routes file.
**routes.rb**

```
namespace :columns do
    root 'columns#index', as: "root"
    get 'post' => 'post#index'
end
```

Usually I set the folders into this one:

```
app/views/columns/columns/index.html.erb  //for the columns index
app/views/columns/post/index.html.erb  //for the post index
```

Comment: `active_link_to` is not a Rails method. Where is it coming from? How is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `active_link_to` gem. But readign at the documentation I would guess that the `active: :exact` option is what you are looking for.

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <%= active_link_to columns_root_path, active: :exact, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
            Columns
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <%= active_link_to columns_post_path, active: :exact, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
            Post
        <% end %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, this one is also correct. I have read the documentation thoroughly and I ended up using `active: :exclusive`. Either way, those 2 conditions are either correct. Thank you for this one.